# Using CVS diff to get line numbers of mofied/added/deleted code

Tags: diff, cvs

I have a very large project where we have made changes to lots of files. Now we need to exactly know which line numbers we have changed/added so that we can run some other tool on that particular line only.

While searching for the answer i found this as an answer to some other question..

```
echo ${f}:
for n in $(git --no-pager blame --line-porcelain $1 |
        awk '/author Not Committed Yet/{if (a && a !~ /author Not Committed Yet/) print a} {a=$0}' |
        awk '{print $3}') ; do
    if (( prev_line > -1 )) ; then
        if (( "$n" > (prev_line + 1) )) ; then
            if (( (prev_line - range_start) > 1 )) ; then
                echo -n "$range_start-$prev_line,"
            else
                echo -n "$range_start,$prev_line,"
            fi
            range_start=$n
        fi
    else
        range_start=$n
    fi
    prev_line=$n
done
if (( "$range_start" != "$prev_line" )) ; then
    echo "$range_start-$prev_line"
else
    echo "$range_start"
fi
```

And it ends up looking like this:

views.py:

> 403,404,533-538,546-548,550-552,554-559,565-567,580-582

It does great.. i need the exact same output using cvs.. Is there any way to get similar output..

Comment: You may want to parse `cvs annotate`.